# Getting the number of deleted rows in Kotlin's Exposed?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I currently have something along the lines of

```
transaction {
    FooTable.deleteWhere { FooTable.BarId eq 1 }
}
```

I want to see how many rows that it successfully deleted (I really just want to make sure there was an entry before and was deleted). Any ideas on how I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
transaction {
   var numberOfDeletedItems = FooTable.deleteWhere { FooTable.BarId eq 1 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Should probably be named ```numberOfDeletdItems```, to be clear. But I guess it was that easy